# Beginning phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phonegap and android, I have create a hello world application [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) and it worked, but I don't know what 's the next step.
 I try to read API document from above link but it isn't easy to understand. For example, I don't know how to communicate between android code and js (how can I call android method from javascript and get value from android code to display in hmtl). I know ajax, but in this case I don't know how to use it.
So, I 'm looking for phonegap android ebook or a complete documents and tutorials.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to bother about android methods in phonegap. Phonegap has its own method to write a android application. You can just use Jquery mobile along with phonegap to built apps. Basically phonegap is a container for jquery mobile helps to built apps with in built style and user interface and also it has own method to interact mobile device with their own methods.

just go through this following documentation and you will get a better idea about phonegap and jquery mobile.

1. [Phonegap UI development with JQuery Mobile](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile)
2. [Phonegap Working Examples](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/phonegap/)

Comment: But what 's happen if I want to use my own method in android code?

Comment: You cant use your android java methods in phonegap. This is a cross platform development, and they have its own methods

Comment: Is anything I can do is use js to call phonegap's api (save data, fire event, access media...) ? And phonegap has full api to take do that?

Comment: You can do all that using javascript. Go through the phonegap documentation.